# How can user receive access token to my service after login with facebook?

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have the restful service with OAuth 2.0 authentication. I want to give users an opportunity to login in my app with their facebook account. My service issues access tokens in response to a post request    `http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=client_id&client_secret=client_secret&username=user&password=password`.

The question is how can I send this request if user doesn't input his password directly?

Answer (score 0):

1. Redirect the user from to the FB screen. 
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + *FacebookClientID* +
   "&redirect_uri=" + Url.Encode(*FacebookRedirectURL*) +"&response_type=code&scope=email" + state
2. Extract "code" from the response
3. Make a Get Request to 
   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + *clientID* + "&redirect_uri=" + *redirectURL* + "&client_secret=" + *clientSecret* + "&code=" + *code*
4. You will now receive the fb access token
5. Use the access token to get user claims
   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=" + *accessToken*
6. After this you call your service and generate your token